# How to install 2 versions of the same application on iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, cfbundleidentifier

I have Application with `Bundle dispaly Name` "BobAppl" and `Bundle identifier` named "org.bob.phone".

I want to install new version of the same application but to save old version as well a.e. on my iPhone I want to see 2 applications: "BobAppl" and "BobApplNew".

Right now if I change `Bundle dispaly Name` to "BobApplNew" I still knock down the "BobAppl".

What I need to do? Need I change `Bundle identifier` only or something else?

Thanks,

Comment: It is better to create an identifier as `org.bob.phone.*` and then you can use it as `org.bob.phone.bob`, `org.bob.phone.bobnew` etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to change the bundle identifier and, optionally, the bundle display name.